# Need to find First Word Using Regular Expression

Tags: regex

HI I have string like `var Sql=" INSERT INTO DB.SCHEMA.TABLE VALUES(?,?,?)"`
Regex pattern i am using (?<=INSERT INTO\b).*;
which is producing the result as `DB.SCHEMA.TABLE VALUES(?,?,?).`

But i need first word immediately after INSERT INTO , which is in this case DB.SCHEMA.TABLE.

What additional expression i should add to Regex pattern to get only first word after Insert Into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
const text = `var Sql=" INSERT INTO DB.SCHEMA.TABLE VALUES(?,?,?)"`;
const regex = /\bINSERT\s+INTO\s+(\w+(?:\.\w+)*|`[^`]*`)/g;
const results = Array.from(text.matchAll(regex), (x) => x[1]);
console.log(results);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R8rNsP/1). *Details*:

- `\bINSERT` - whole word `INSERT`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `INTO` - an `INTO` word
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `` (\w+(?:.\w+)*|`[^`]*`) `` - Group 1: one or more word chars and then zero or more occurrences of `.` and one or more word chars, or a backtick, zero or more chars other than backtick and then a backtick char.